# What does "Has been cloaked" mean?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on moving some types to a matching file refactoring in a VB.NET application written years ago by someone whose no longer with us. He tended to put lots of classes in a file. For example, he'd put a dozen classes into a BaseClases.vb file. It has become hard to find those classes, so I started performing this refactoring to help me as I support the app.

However, every time I'd refactor a type into a separate class file, VS 2019 would generate a message that reads like this:

"The item SomeClass.vb has been cloaked. See output tool window for information on any other errors."

I'd look at the Errors window but didn't see anything obvious. Although there's lots of other errors unrelated to this, so it might be there, and I've missed it in the crowd of errors.

I've searched SO for the phrase "has been cloaked". It only brought up 2 posts, neither of which addressed the situation I'm in.

So, what does it mean to have a new class cloaked? From what is it being cloaked?

Comment: Cloak in general means hidden. Did you remove the class definitions from the file with multiple class definitions after your created the new class file? Look at the access level of your new class as well.

Comment: https://elieg.com/blog/tfs-tips-cloaking-folders-and-files/

Comment: Interesting Hans. So, refactoring might cause VS 2019 to cloak classes automatically. Thank you for sharing that link.